# Waking network radios in iOS

Tags: ios, reachability

If I leave my device untouched for a while, the radios sleep to conserve power. If I check reachability in this state, I learn that the host I am checking for is unreachable. How can I wake the radio back up? Do I need to explicitly make a network call? Can I detect that the reason the network is unreachable is that the radio is asleep?

The basic check I'm doing works like this (taken from Apple's Reachability):

```
// The setup
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, [@"myserver.example.com" UTF8String]);
    }
    return self;
}

// The check
- (BOOL)isReachable
{
    return [self currentReachabilityStatus] != NotReachable;
}

// For reference
- (NetworkStatus)currentReachabilityStatus
{
    NSAssert(_reachabilityRef != NULL, @"currentNetworkStatus called with NULL SCNetworkReachabilityRef");
    NetworkStatus returnValue = NotReachable;
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

    if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(_reachabilityRef, &flags))
    {
        returnValue = [self networkStatusForFlags:flags];
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: If I try to make a URL request, it fails for lack of internet connection. If I leave my app and open Safari, the internet connection is restored. I'm testing with a device that has no SIM but is connected to a WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

You don't manage the device's radio. iOS does that for you.

Reachability says if the internet is reachable or not, not what radios are on or off. You can be reachable by cell, even if wifi is on (or just as easily, reachable by wifi, even if cell is available).

For the most part, radio power usage will be dwarfed by the screen's power usage. `NSURLSessionConfiguration` has a `discretionary` property that can be a hint to the OS that you don't need this request to start right away, but, that property is already ignored by background session tasks, to opt people into helping to save power.

Comment: Sure, and perhaps this a bug in 7.0.3 but when I try to make requests in my app when the WiFi is sleeping, they fail saying the device isn't connected to the internet. If I hit the home button and go into Safari, I am reconnected to the WiFi. Perhaps Safari is using an internal API?